# Como colocar um rabiscado na página

Tags: html, css, css3

Como colocar um rabiscado laranja como na imagem abaixo na pagina html?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o mais facil seria ter esse rabisco como imagem `.png` e no elemento texto você colocar a propriedade `background:url('nome_da_imagem.png')`

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode usar como um backgroun-image para o texto. tipo nesse exemplo

```css
h1 {
    background-image: url(https://ubisafe.org/images/svg-stroke-brush-2.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: aliceblue;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor.
</h1>
<br>
<h1>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor. Lorem, ipsum dolor.
</h1>
```

Eu indico que vc use um SVG como imagem, assim ela pode ser melhor manipulada pelo CSS e tem uma resolução melhor pra qualquer tamanho

Comment: Isso que queria, obrigado pela dica Hugo!